# How to correct by writing a good method of deleting data?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wrote this method which is supposed to delete a user from the database from the provide id. This method passes but it does not delete a user as expected. And I need help.

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{matricule}")
public ResponseEntity supprimerUtilisateur( 
@PathVariable(name="matricule") String matricule) {
    if(matricule == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Impossible de supprimer un utilisateur, matricule null");
    }
    Utilisateur utilisateur = utilisateurRepository.getOne(matricule);

    if(utilisateur == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }


    return ResponseEntity.ok("Utilisateur supprimé avec succès!");
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: More importantly, where is the deletion call happening? I don't see anywhere in the controller where you are actually deleting the user.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, the problem has been corrected with UserRepository.deleteById (code);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your code you missed the delete part

Assuming you are using Spring Data Repository you can do it like this

```
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{matricule}")
public ResponseEntity supprimerUtilisateur( 
@PathVariable(name="matricule") String matricule) {
    if(matricule == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Impossible de supprimer un utilisateur, matricule null");
    }
    Utilisateur utilisateur = utilisateurRepository.getOne(matricule);
    if(utilisateur == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    // Pass utilisateur => primaryKey in deleteById method
    utilisateurRepository.deleteById(utilisateur.getId());

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Utilisateur supprimé avec succès!");
}
```